# Why are the Prismatic Dragon's attack bonuses wrong?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dragons

### The Question

I've been fiddling with the Epic Dragon statblocks recently, as they're given on the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/monsters/dragonEpic.htm), and I've found something that bugs me: some of the calculations are inconsistent, and some of them are just *wrong*.

While the saves conform to the Epic advancement rules after 20HD, the BAB *doesn't*, instead just continuing to increase at +1 per HD - and then, when calculating attack bonuses, the result is a few points lower than it should be considering the given base attack and Str score. At first I thought they might have just made a mistake listing the base attack and then properly calculated the attack bonuses with the Epic rules, but when I ran the numbers it turned out that it was even lower than the given value when calculated that way.

Did I miss something, or have they just fudged it? Should I recalculate the saves without Epic progression to make it match? Should I recalculate the attack bonuses *with*?

### The Maths

Prismatic Dragon (Young): 33HD, Str 37, BAB as given: +33, Attack bonus as given: +42.

- Calculations with numbers as given:

  Str bonus is (37-10)/2 = 13.5, rounds down to **13**
  Attack bonus should be 33 + 13 = **+46**
- Calculations corrected for Epic BAB progression:

  At level 33, Epic BAB is an additional +7 for a total of **+27**
  Str bonus is +13; attack bonus should then be 27 + 13 = **+40**
- Final Numbers:

  - Attack bonus as given: +42
  - Attack bonus as it should be with given numbers: +46
  - Attack bonus when corrected for Epic BAB in accordance with use of Epic save rules: +40

Ideas I have as to why this is and how it should actually be working: 0

Answer (score 7):

Remember to account for the size modifier.  A Young prismatic dragon is gargantuan, so it gets a -4 penalty to attack rolls.

I don't know much about epic progression, but I would guess that it only applies to leveled characters and not to monsters.  These dragons appear to be using the [standard progression](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm) of one BAB per hit die.  There are nonepic monsters, for example the Great Wyrm black dragon, which have one BAB per hit die even past 20 hit dice; presumably epic monsters can do the same.

Comment: That would explain it. Forgot about size penalty to attack modifier. Thank you.

Comment: The epic progression only applies to BAB given by class levels, not to racial HD. I can't remember who told me but it was on this site.

Comment: @Zachiel You are correct. Racial Hit Dice are not effected by linear _character class_ progression. Since dragons have 'good' BAB - a 40 Hit Dice dragon would have a BAB of +40.